# Prevent reference loop properties from serializing

Tags: serialization, entity-framework-core, many-to-many

I am getting a buffer exception in one of my unit tests on my controllers for a aspnet.core project.

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Cannot write more bytes to the buffer than the configured maximum buffer size: 2147483647

Digging into it - it is because of a many to many relationship I have configured where I have included the related collection in the response to an entity:

My model(s):

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key] public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
    public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }
    public Guid? ManagerId { get; set; }
    public Guid AddressId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeRole> EmployeeRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Manager { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeProject> Projects { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeProject
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }

    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

My context configuration:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeProject>(employeeProject =>
        {
            employeeProject.HasKey(ep => new {ep.EmployeeId, ep.ProjectId});
            employeeProject.HasOne(ep => ep.Project)
                .WithMany(p => p.EmployeeProjects)
                .HasForeignKey(ep => ep.ProjectId);
            employeeProject.HasOne(ep => ep.Employee)
                .WithMany(e => e.Projects)
                .HasForeignKey(ep => ep.EmployeeId);

        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>(emp =>
        {
            emp.HasKey(e => e.Id);
            emp.Property(p => p.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            emp.HasMany(e => e.EmployeeRoles);
            emp.HasOne(e => e.Manager).WithMany(e => e.Employees).IsRequired(false);
            emp.HasOne(e => e.Address).WithOne(a => a.Employee)
                .HasForeignKey<Employee>(e => e.AddressId);
            emp.HasMany(e => e.Projects);
        });
```

The problem is I want to include the ICollection with my result of context.Employess.  i.e.

```
ctx.Employees.Include(e => e.Projects).ToListAsync();
```

This is resulting in all of the related Employee records to be included on each EmployeeProject record, which in turn has the related ICollection and so on.  i.e.

```
[
    {
       "Id": "1",
       "Projects": [
                      {
                         "EmployeId": "1"
                         "ProjectId": "A"
                         "Employee": 
                                    {
                                         "Id": "1"
                                         "Projects": [
                                                        {
                                                            "EmployeId": "1"
                                                             "ProjectId": "A"
                                                             "Employee":
```

And so on.

This when returned in a web response results in a buffer overflow.

I am ignoring the ReferenceLoopHandling in my configuration:

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        });
```

From the Newtonsoft.Json namespace

```
/// <summary>Ignore loop references and do not serialize.</summary>
Ignore,
/// <summary>Serialize loop references.</summary>
Serialize,
```

Comment: You don't tell how you configure your unit tests but it seems that `services.AddMvc()` isn't added/mocked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these attributes :

`[JsonObject(IsReference = true)]`
This attribute to top of your **Class** and

`[JsonIgnore]` 
This attribute to top of your **Property** which is causing the reference loop.

I hope I understand your problem clearly.